# if with 2 conditions to return 2 different possible values

Tags: vba, excel

i am writing a code that checks if the row is yellow and if the value of a cell is true, if both are positive, it should return a blank row and uncheck the checkbox list. Otherwise, it should return a yellow row. I have written the following code, but it is not working. I would appreciate your help

```
Sub desmarcar_antigos()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 130 To 2 Step -1
        If Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            If Cells(i, 9).Value = "TRUE" Then
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 And Sheets("Planilha").CheckBox1.Value = False
            Else
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `And` to run two statements in a single line. Change this line:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 And Sheets("Planilha").CheckBox1.Value = False
```

To:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Sheets("Planilha").CheckBox1.Value = False
```

If you really want to run two statements on a single line, you can use `:`. For example:

```
Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 : Sheets("Planilha").CheckBox1.Value = False
```

but it should be discouraged.

Also, you can check both your conditions using a single `If`. That way, your `Else` will run if either fails:

```
If Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And Cells(i, 9).Value = "TRUE" Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Sheets("Planilha").CheckBox1.Value = False
Else
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If
```

Comment: Psst...its Rows() not Ows() ;)